# Draw first few sides of a polygon thicker than the remaining sides

Tags: graphics

I use the following code to draw an n-polygon where the first `t` sides are meant to be thicker than the remaining sides:

```
PolyAngT[x_, s_, \[Phi]_, n_, t_, tr_] := 
 Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.03]], Line[s (x + # & /@ (Through[{Cos, Sin}[Pi (#/3.5 + \[Phi] \[Pi]/180)]] & /@Range[0, t]))]}, 
    {EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]], Line[s (x + # & /@ (Through[{Cos, Sin}[Pi (#/3.5 + \[Phi] \[Pi]/180)]] & /@ Range[t, n]))]}}]
```

...but the thicknesses don't "take". I *do* get a difference in thickness, but it isn't controllable. That is, if I replace the `Thickness` commands with just `Thick` in the first case, and nothing in the second, I get the same drawing. Suggests to me that my thickness commands are being re-scaled, but I'm not sophisticated enough to know why. Any help appreciated, thank you!

To be clear, for 'graphic design' reasons, I want to make the first few sides rather thicker than the remaining sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 10;
t = 4;
radius = 1;
startingangle = Pi/2;

coords = CirclePoints[{radius, startingangle}, n];

{part1, part2} = {Take[coords, t], Append[First @ coords] @ Drop[coords, t - 1] };

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[Opacity[.5, LightBlue]], Polygon @ coords, 
  Opacity[.5], CapForm["Round"], 
  AbsoluteThickness[10], Red, Line @ part1, 
  AbsoluteThickness[15], Orange, Line @ part2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) with `Polygon@coords` and style the cells (polygons, lines, points) as desired using [`MeshCellStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html) based on the cell indices:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Polygon @ coords, 
 MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Blue, Thick}], 
  {1, _?(GreaterEqualThan[t])} -> 
    Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[15], Orange], 
  {1, _?(LessThan[t])} ->
   Directive[CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], AbsoluteThickness[10], Red]}]
```

[image]